# AWS Device Farm.How can i save the custom report being generated after the test case into my local space

Tags: eclipse, maven, automation, appium, aws-device-farm

I am working with AWS device farm.My test script when run on my local system works as expected and generates a report in my local system at specified path.Now when i run the code in the device farm the report does not get generated.Am i missing something?

### This is my test code to write the test cases to a html report.

```
package testOutput;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import net.dongliu.apk.parser.ApkFile;
import net.dongliu.apk.parser.bean.ApkMeta;
import report.TestReportSteps;

public class TestResultHtml {
    public static void WriteResultToHtml(List<TestReportSteps> items, String getCurrentDateTime, String getCurrentTime) {
        try {String filePath="C:\\\\Appium\\\\app-qc-debug.apk";
     ApkFile apkFile = new ApkFile(new File(filePath));
        ApkMeta apkMeta = apkFile.getApkMeta();

        String Version=apkMeta.getVersionName();
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy, HH:mm:ss");
            Date dateobj = new Date();
            String currentDateTime = df.format(dateobj);

            StringBuilder color = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder status = new StringBuilder();
            // define a HTML String Builder
            StringBuilder actualResult = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder htmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            // append html header and title
            htmlStringBuilder.append(
                    "<html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css\" integrity=\"sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\">\r\n"
                            + "<script src=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js\" integrity=\"sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script><title>Appium Test </title></head>");
            // append body
            htmlStringBuilder.append("<body>");
            // append table
            //if (count == 0) 
            {
                htmlStringBuilder.append("<table class=\"table table-striped table-bordered\">");
                htmlStringBuilder.append("<tr><th style=\"background-color:#a6a6a6\">Date Time</th><td>"
                        + currentDateTime
                        + "</td><th style=\"background-color:#a6a6a6\">Environment Tested</th><td>QC</td></tr>"
                        + "<tr><th style=\"background-color:#a6a6a6\">OS</th><td>Android</td><th style=\"background-color:#a6a6a6\">Application</th><td>app-qc-debug.apk</td></tr>"
                        + "<tr><th style=\"background-color:#a6a6a6\">Script Name</th><td colspan=\""
                        + 3
                        + "\">Cityvan Workflow</td>"
                        + "<th style=\"background-color:#a6a6a6\">Build Version</th><td>"+Version+"</td></tr><tr><th style=\"background-color:#a6a6a6\">Objective</th><td colspan=\""
                        + 3 + "\">To verify that cityvan app is working as expected</td><tr><tr></table>");
            }
            // append row
            htmlStringBuilder.append("<table class=\"table table-striped\">");
            htmlStringBuilder.append(
                    "<thead style=\"background-color:#007acc\"><tr><th><b>TestObjective</b></th><th><b>StepName</b></th><th><b>StepDescription</b></th><th><b>ExpectedResult</b></th><th><b>ActualResult</b></th><th><b>Status</b></th><th><b>Screenshot</b></th></tr></thead><tbody>");
            // append row
            for (TestReportSteps a : items) {

                if (!a.getActualResultFail().isEmpty()) {
                    status.append("Fail");
                    color.append("red");
                    actualResult.append(a.getActualResultFail());
                } else {
                    status.append("Pass");
                    color.append("green");
                    actualResult.append(a.getActualResultPass());
                }
                if (a.getScreenshotPath()!=null) 
                {
                    htmlStringBuilder.append("<tr><td>" + a.getTestObjective() + "</td><td>" + a.getStepName()
                            + "</td><td>" + a.getStepDescription() + "</td><td>" + a.getExpectedResult() + "</td><td>"
                            + actualResult + "</td><td style=\"color:" + color + ";font-weight:bolder;\">" + status
                            + "</td><td><a href=\"" + a.getScreenshotPath() + "\">Click here</a></td></tr>");
                }
                else 
                {
                    htmlStringBuilder.append("<tr><td style=\"font-weight:bold\">" + a.getTestObjective() + "</td><td>"
                            + a.getStepName() + "</td><td>" + a.getStepDescription() + "</td><td>"
                            + a.getExpectedResult() + "</td><td>" + actualResult + "</td><td style=\"color:" + color
                            + ";font-weight:bolder;\">" + status + "</td><td></td></tr>");
                }
                actualResult.delete(0, actualResult.length());
                color.delete(0, color.length());
                status.delete(0, status.length());
            }
            // close html file
            htmlStringBuilder.append("</tbody></table></body></html>");

            // write html string content to a file
            String htmlFilepath = "";

            htmlFilepath = "D:\\FinalAppiumWorkspace\\AppiumMavenProject2\\src\\test\\java\\testOutput\\HtmlReport\\" + getCurrentDateTime + "\\testfile"
                    + getCurrentTime + "\\testfile.html";

            WriteToFile(htmlStringBuilder.toString(), htmlFilepath);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void WriteToFile(String fileContent, String fileName) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File(fileName);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        PrintWriter out = null;
        if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) 
        {
            out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName), true));
            out.append(fileContent);
            out.close();
        } else 
        {
            // write to file with OutputStreamWriter
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsoluteFile(), false);
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
            writer.write(fileContent);
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path the code is referencing doesn't exist in the device host for the farm. The Device Host for android tests is a Linux machine and from my experience we have access to the `tmp` directory. By using the [custom artifacts](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/custom-artifacts-on-aws-device-farm/) feature of Device Farm and the tmp directory this should be possible. Try changing the path to the html file to:

```
htmlFilepath = "/tmp/reports/testfile.html";
```

Then, using the web console, explicitly mark that directory to be exported.

[image: specify device state page]

Once the testes finish, you should see a link for `customer artifacts`.

[image]

Additionally, you may be interested in other options for test reports like

- [extent reports](http://extentreports.com/)
- [Allure reports](http://allure.qatools.ru/)

rather than writing your own from scratch.

HTH

-James

Answer (score 1):

For the users who are receiving `java.io.FileNotFoundException:(Permission denied)` exception while trying to save test logs/reports in `$WORKING_DIRECTORY` or any other path. You can use `$DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR` to save your artifacts, this worked for me.

```
String artifactsDir = System.getenv("DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR");
```

Use this directory to store any artifacts.

Comment: Not defined for me.