# AWS Device farm results reporting

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, appium, aws-device-farm

is there someone to help me with reporting in AWS device farm? 
The problem is that all tests cases are in one test suite -> one failed test case causes whole test suite failed and which one is failed is not clear(first image). I expect there is a list of all testcases one by one and it is clear what is failed or passed like it is on second image. Some tips?
[Have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4plxJ.png)
[Need this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJbeT.png)

Answer (score 0):

For the standard environment check out my answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50419900/112233

For the custom environment you can use the artifacts section of the testspec.yml file to extract certain files from the host machine into the customer artifacts zip.